# is $(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty) = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1, \infty)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am curious if $(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty) = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1, \infty)$.

I am trying to show the domain of $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-x}$. I checked my work on an online calculator, but since it gave the latter answer, I'm not sure if I got it right.

Comment: $\frac12{{}{}}$?

Comment: The set on the right (the union of the three intervals) is the correct answer.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't know what you're saying.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown was prompting you to consider whether $\frac12$ is in the set on the left side of your equation, and then to consider whether it is in the set on the right side of your equation.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang So the one on the left is incorrect?

Comment: @MarkS. Ohh, I see what you're saying. I understand what I did wrong now.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The sets are obviously not equal. But if you mean that they are equal in size than yes, they are

Comment: @StanTendijck I was asking if they were the same. I can tell they aren't now.

Comment: @LuminousNutria Yes, the one on the left is incorrect. The equality in the question title is false.  The number $\frac{1}{2}$ is in the set on the left, but not the set on the right.

Comment: What made you think the answer was the set on the left?  (Not a rhetorical question; I'm honestly interested)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I'm not sure, I was thinking in integers I guess.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  You'd be right if the question were for which integers the function is defined.  But over real numbers there's a big difference.

Comment: I would write the domain as $\Bbb R\setminus\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is
>   $\,(-\infty,\,0)\cup(1,\,\infty)=(-\infty,\,0)\cup(0,\,1)\cup(1,\,\infty)\,$?

The answer is no, because $\,(0,\,1)\not\subset(-\infty,\,0)\cup(1,\,\infty)\,$ and $\,(0,\,1)\subset(-\infty,\,0)\cup(0,\,1)\cup(1,\,\infty)\,$. Since both sets do not contain the same elements, they cannot be equal.

The domain of $\, g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-x}$ is equal to the set

$\,\mathbb{R}\setminus\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\;x^2-x=0\}=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,\,0\}$

since $x^2-x=0\Longleftrightarrow x(x-1)=0 \Rightarrow x=0\,$ *or* $\,x=1$.

Note that $\,\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,\,0\}=(-\infty,\,0)\cup(0,\,1)\cup(1,\,\infty)\,$.

Answer (score 0):

$g(x)= \frac 1  {x^2-x}$ is defined except when the denominator $x^2-x=x(x-1)=0$, i.e., $x \in ${$0$,$1$}.  The domain of $g$ is therefore $\mathbb R$ \ {$0$,$1$} $= (-\infty, 0) \cup (0,1) \cup (1,\infty)$.  That is different from $ (-\infty, 0) \cup (1,\infty),$ because the domain includes $x \in (0,1)$, just not $x \in $ {$0$,$1$}.